# Force.com sites standard object permission

Tags: force.com-sites, permissions

I have developed a force.com sites and at the backend I want to check delete permission on standard objects and it shows that I cannot update or delete contact records .

Is it possible to give edit and delete permission on Contact records for force.com sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with bit of modifications.

1. Create a separate `class without sharing`.
2. Write logic to edit and delete the Contact records in methods.
3. Conditionally call these methods depending on your criterias.

Note : From metadata you will never get   `isUpdatable` value true for site user and Contact object.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you cannot provide those permissions .But there is a workaround ,you can create a custom Contact Object and write a trigger to run under the system context on the custom object to sync back the data to the contact record .

But in theory you cannot update contacts with Force.com sites due to license restrictions